# После записи строки в dict меняется ее содержимое

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

```
import os

username = os.environ.get("username")
password = os.environ.get("password")
ip = os.environ.get("untrusted_ip")
port = os.environ.get("untrusted_port")

data = {
   "username": username,
   "password": password,
   "ip": ip,
   "port": port,
}

print(username)
print(data)
```

Результат работы кода:

```
2WLjulhUGPAhNJ6bANmr1EXp3jjmQDа

{'username': '2WLjulhUGPAhNJ6bANmr1EXp3jjmQD\udcd0\udcb0', 'password': 
'IMAn5BifVgN2k1gyVwmr7fGhqG94li', 'ip': '10.0.2.2', 'port': '39540'}
```

Почему меняется содержимое data["username"] ? И как это исправить.
Код запускаю на ubuntu server, версия python 3

Comment: Содержимое не меняется, просто сочетание `'\udcd0\udcb0'` - это то что через `print` отображается как `а`. Можете проверить с помощью `print('\udcd0\udcb0')`.

Comment: как можно это исправить?

Comment: чтобы отображалось а

Comment: Выводите значение через `print`: `print(data["username"])`

Comment: почему тогда print(username) все нормально выводит?

Comment: `'\udcd0\udcb0'` - это нормально. Оставьте как есть.

Answer (score 1):

Если есть сильное желание избавиться от кодированных суррогатных пар, то можно сделать такой костыль:

```
c = '2WLjulhUGPAhNJ6bANmr1EXp3jjmQD\udcd0\udcb0'
print(c.encode('utf-8', 'surrogateescape').decode('utf-8'))
```

Получим

```
2WLjulhUGPAhNJ6bANmr1EXp3jjmQDа
```